# After exporting from Darktable, I continue getting a message stating, "IMG...CR2 file is currently unavailable"

Tags: raw, darktable, export

I'm about 2 weeks new to darktable. I (almost) successfully imported, edited & exported my current project. When I was done editing in darktable, I noticed that about 32 photos didn't export into my designated folder on my desktop. When I go back in to export the remaining files, I continue getting a message stating, "IMG...CR2 file is currently unavailable".

Comment: More info is needed. Where are/were the original files kept? Did they stay there?  What are the import/export darktable settings you have set in preferences. More info  is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your time in helping me troubleshoot this! I appreciate your time! I did move my color corrected file into a master file (where my raws are also kept in a separate sub folder) on my desktop. Then read that moving the folder might be an issue, so moved it back to my desktop. The raws haven't been moved at all. Bear with me, I'm still learning the import/export preferences. Is there a specific setting I should be looking into?

Comment: Alaska Man...Here are the export selected preferences; target storage=file on disk (I even tried to create a new folder to see if that made a difference), on conflict=skip, file format=JPEG 2000, format=jp2, quality=100, DCP mode=off, max size=0x0, allow upscaling=no, high quality resampling=yes, profile=Adobe RGB (compatible), intent=image settings, style=none

Comment: @Megan, please edit your question to include new information, such that people don't need to go through the comments to understand your question. No need to write "edit" or "update", just incorporate the additional information in your question as if you're writing it for the first time.

Comment: * file format=JPEG 2000, format=jp2*  That is not the same format as standard JPEG.  It's different and many applications cannot read these files.  Depending on how your system or applications handle files they may not even list files with that extension to select from in some situations - e.g. they'll only show files they consider relevant.  Not sure if that's your problem, but something to be aware of.